# Can I extract the GPG public key if I have an encrypted file, the private key pgp file, and the pass phrase?

Tags: gpg

I am working on a project where I have been provided with a GPG private key in armor text format, the pass phrase, and a file that was encrypted with the public key. The public key is not available however. I have verified the parts I have by importing the private key and decrypting the sample file, so I know the 3 bits I have are working.

Is there any option to recreate the public key from these 3 parts that I have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already imported the private key with `gpg --import private.asc` you can export the public key with `gpg --export <id>`. By default, it only exports the public key.